# Automatic underclocking processor at high temperatures for raspberry pi 4 with ubuntu 20.04

Tags: raspberrypi, overheating

I have just got raspberry pi 4 B.
I have installed only ubuntu 20.04 on it.
I want to know like raspbian does new ubuntu (now with support for raspberry pi) automatically underclocks my processor at high temperatures, which was not included in older versions.
Or I have to use 'thermald' still now?
If so is there any other methods/tools too.
Thanks in advance.
Also does the same come with ubuntu 20.10 desktop.

Comment: I honestly have no idea about it underclocking automatically, but are you experiencing overheating?  Do you have a case around the Raspberry Pi with a heatsink on the chips?  If you do and you have a fan installed, try making it so the fan blows up and out instead of down and in.  It will push more air out and remove the heat that way, instead of circulating it around the Pi when it blows in.

Comment: I have heatsink and fan. Not notted any overheating. But i was just worried so asked thinking is it necessary to install raspbian for long time use.

Comment: Yeah, when I got my Pi 4 I was experiencing overheating and it was not underclocking at all.  I talked to one of my friends and he suggested I turn the fan over and I did and it never overheated since.

Comment: What os were u using?

Comment: Raspian at the time.  It was when I was running things that were higher in graphics it would do it.  I had the heatsinks and everything installed.  I noticed that it would start to get choppy before it would overheat and turn off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know every modern CPU, no matter if desktop, laptop or singleboard computer like Raspberry Pi (even the first version) do automatic throtteling in the hardware. It's independent from the OS you installed. If it gets too hot even when it throtteled back to the lowest frequency you can't usually kill your hardware, it simply shuts off then.

The throtteling which is done by the OS is to reduce frequency if the CPU has not much load which prevents heating the CPU when there's nothing to do. I didn't try but this should be done by every modern Linux distribution.

You can read out the current CPU frequency to check if that works. Unfortunately I can't tell you how to do that (have no Raspberry Pi for checking right now)